# How do I test for a condition across a range of columns in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to test for a condition across a range of columns. The data looks something like this

```
      Name DPD_1 DPD_2 DPD_3 Default_flag
 1:    A    46    63   138         TRUE
 2:    B    12    82    33        FALSE
 3:    C    95    71    55         TRUE
 4:    D    57   133   116         TRUE
 5:    E    48    27   137         TRUE
```

in the code I need to test if any of DPD_1, DPD_2 or DPD_3 are greater than 90, in which case the Default_flag gets set to TRUE.

The code I am using for this is given below

```
df1 <- data.table(Name = LETTERS[1:10],DPD_1 = sample(1:100,10),DPD_2 = sample(1:200,10),DPD_3 = sample(1:200,10) )
df1[,Default_flag := ifelse((DPD_1>=90 | DPD_2>=90 | DPD_3>=90 ),TRUE,FALSE)]
```

Now the problem is with some datasets I need to increase the DPD checks from DPD_1 to say DPD_24 (checking for 24 columns, instead of just 3 in the current example). Is there anyway i can avoid specifying each DPDnumber in the ifelse statement. I am happy to lose the ifelse statement and if some version of apply can work, i would be happy to use that too.

Comment: You *might* convert all `DPD_*` columns into a matrix, though I don't necessarily recommend it. (If you did, you could use row-wise comparisons.) You could also convert wide-to-tall (perhaps with `tidyr::gather`), group by row, and then convert back to wide. Both are imperfect and have various inefficiencies. (Edit: or you could use akrun's answer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `|` after specifying the columns of interest in `.SDcols`

```
df1[, Default_flag :=  Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `>=`, 90)), .SDcols = DPD_1:DPD_3]
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's comment, if we need to create a function to automatically detect the column names, then use `grep` to get the column names based on a pattern.  The function below takes the datasets, a pattern ('pat'), a value to compare ('val') and 'n' i.e. the number of columns of a particular pattern

```
f1 <- function(dat, pat, val, n){
  tmp <- as.data.table(dat)
  nm1 <- head(grep(pat, names(tmp), value = TRUE), n)
  tmp[, Default_flag := Reduce(`|`,lapply(.SD, `>=`, val)), .SDcols = nm1][]
}

f1(df1, "DPD", 90, 2)
f1(df1, "DPD", 90, 3)
```

---

As per @aelwan's request an option using `tidyverse` would be

```
library(tidyverse)
f2 <- function(dat, pat, val, n){
  pat <- quo_name(enquo(pat))
  nm1 <- head(grep(pat, names(dat), value = TRUE), n)

  dat %>%
      mutate_at(vars(nm1), funs(.>= val)) %>%
      select_at(nm1) %>%
      reduce(`|`) %>%
      mutate(dat, Default_flag = .) 

}

f2(df1, DPD, 90, 2)
f2(df1, DPD, 90, 3)
```

---

```
identical(f1(df1, "DPD", 90, 2), as.data.table(f2(df1, DPD, 90, 2)))
#[1] TRUE
identical(f1(df1, "DPD", 90, 3), as.data.table(f2(df1, DPD, 90, 3)))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: works like a charm!! I am getting a little greedy here, but how would i go about creating a function wherein I take the value 3 (from DPD_3) as an input and then use the Reduce function the way you have done..esesentially, i am trying to parameterise the DPD1_DPDn, where n is an input. Any pointers would be great

Comment: @ashleych  Did you meant instead of 90, it should be `1, 2, 3` for `DPD_1`, DPD_2, and DPD_3 ?

Comment: No, the test condition continues to be 90 for all the columns. But as I do not know the number of columns Id have to check, I want to code in such a way that the user calls a function with the number of columns to check - say 15, for example. In which case your reduce function should work like df1[, Default_flag :=  Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `>=`, 90)), .SDcols = DPD_1:DPD_15]

Comment: @ashleych  Thanks for the clarification.  I updated with a function

Comment: @akrun
Many thanks for your answer. I will highly appreciate if you could show how it can be done using dplyr if possible.

Comment: @ashleych  I think I misunderstood your earlier comment.  Updated to include `n` also

Comment: @aelwan  Updated the post.  Thanks for your comments

Comment: @akrun Many thanks for updating your answer. I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: @aelwan, I've added an alternative `tidyverse` solution to akrun's you might be interested in.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative to [@akrun's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46127223/8475145) is a `tidyverse` solution which makes use of the `tidyr::gather` function (as suggested by @r2evans in the comments).

The relevant variable names are detected using `dplyr::starts_with` rather than `grep`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))  

set.seed(12345)
df1 <- tibble(Name = LETTERS[1:10],
              DPD_1 = sample(1:100,10),
              DPD_2 = sample(1:200,10),
              DPD_3 = sample(1:200,10))

df1 %>%
  select(Name, starts_with("DPD_")) %>%
  gather(DPD_name, DPD_value, -Name) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Default_Flag = any(DPD_value > 90)) %>%
  { left_join(df1, ., by = "Name") }

#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>     Name DPD_1 DPD_2 DPD_3 Default_Flag
#>    <chr> <int> <int> <int>        <lgl>
#>  1     A    73     7    91         TRUE
#>  2     B    87    31    66        FALSE
#>  3     C    75   146   192         TRUE
#>  4     D    86     1   140         TRUE
#>  5     E    44    77   127         TRUE
#>  6     F    16    91    77         TRUE
#>  7     G    31    76   136         TRUE
#>  8     H    48    78   106         TRUE
#>  9     I    67    35    44        FALSE
#> 10     J    91   182    93         TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = " Name DPD_1 DPD_2 DPD_3 Default_flag    
 1:    A    46    63   138         TRUE
             2:    B    12    82    33        FALSE
             3:    C    95    71    55         TRUE
             4:    D    57   133   116         TRUE
             5:    E    48    27   137         TRUE")
df

df$Df.flag <- apply(df[, colnames(df) %in% paste0("DPD_", (1:3))],
                 1, 
                 function(x) any(x > 90))
df
```

Comment: Akrun's answer works best for my particular example, but your answer is good to know as it can be used in a number of situations; more versatile.

Comment: when i ran your code as is, it worked fine, but when i ran it on my reproducible example it throws an error                        Error in apply(df1[, colnames(df1) %in% paste0("DPD_", (1:3))], 1, function(x) any(x >  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length.  Also what does the 1 after the paste0 bit do?

Comment: 1 is the "margin", this is apply works rowwise. The error message means something went wrong when filtering or Looping through the Matrix.